# iPhone with Safari not interpreting @media correct

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

On my Website and on a desktop-screen, the text-body should not be at the top of page - but, with the iPhone - the text must be at the top. To display on/off i made a class with some empty paragraphs -> the iPhone should not display this class. The code below is NOT working on my iPhone 6+ with Safari - however it's perfect with iPhone 6+ and FireFox!

Html Code:

```
      <div class="display-breaks">
      <p> </p>
      <p> </p>
      </div>
```

CSS....

```
 // Set Defaults-> display the paragraphs
 .display-breaks { display: block; }
```

..........

```
// hide the paragraphs's
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){         
   .display-breaks { display: none !important; }
}
```

If i play around on my desktop with the width of the Website the top of the text is jumping up and down- so somehow the display: on/off is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your max-width to 599px.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
```

}

UPDATE: Do you have a meta viewport tag? It worked my iPhone 7+ using Safari just after I added the meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Still the same! Okay with Firefox - not okay with Safari.

Comment: Tryed the display: none alone:

Comment: @user2500308 Do you have a meta viewport in your HTML? The code worked in my 7+ with max-width 480px just until I added the meta tag.

Comment: Tried the -> .display-breaks { display: none !important; }  alone without any conditional statement -> Still no impact on Safari but okay on Firefox.

Comment: meta-tag:   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = device-width" />

Comment: @user2500308 that’s weird. The code worked just fine using your meta tag.

Comment: definitly weird - the display: none is having no effect at all!? Finally i guess the <meta name..> and the @media statement are okay, but the "display-breaks class" is not working as it should.